# Validate sum of child collection against value on parent

Tags: csla

Using CSLA, I have a parent with a budget property set to x.  This parent can have any number of child detail objects.  I need to implement a validation rule on the parent that is valid only when the sum of the budget property of all the children add up the the value of the budget property defined on the parent.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you still don't have it, add this `using` to the parent class:

```
using Csla.Rules;
```

Then add the following rule to `AddBusinessRules()` in the parent:

```
BusinessRules.AddRule<MyParent>(MyDetailsProperty,
    o =>
    {
        return o.Budget == o.MyDetails.Sum(d => d.Budget);
    }, "The value of the budget for parent and details do not match.");
```

The rule returns `true` if the value of Budget in the parent is equal to the sum of Budget in the children.

To make this work you need to trigger the check of the rule whenever the children change, in the parent class add the following:

```
protected override void OnChildChanged(Csla.Core.ChildChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnChildChanged(e);
    BusinessRules.CheckRules(MyDetailsProperty);
}
```

I'm using CSLA version 4.5 but this works with some previous versions too. Unfortunately I don't have the exact version number from which you will be able to use this.